# whois command giving out of date result

Tags: whois

I am running a whois command which is giving me different results on 2 different servers.

Both servers are running ubuntu 16.04 lts, both have the same version of whois installed, both have the same DNS servers and finally both are using the same whois server.

However when I run the command on 1 server I get an out of date response - the domain renewed in January.  The second server shows the correct response.

I have tried running

```
sudo service nscd restart
```

on the out of date server, but this didnt resolve the issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Start by showing the whois commands you use and their results. Without obfuscation. `nscd` will have no influence on whois results.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to using the geektools whois server which gives me the answers I want